# Function to create collapseable print_r() var_dump()?

Tags: php

You've probably familiar with this output from print_r:

```
Hierarchy Object
(
    [parent:private] => Hierarchy Object
        (
            [parent:private] => 
            [children:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [level:private] => 0
            [price_modes:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [id:protected] => 
            [left_id:protected] => 
            [right_id:protected] => 
            [name:protected] => 
            [validationFailures:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_new:private] => 1
            [_deleted:private] => 
            [modifiedColumns:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [level:private] => 1
    [price_modes:private] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

Is there anything that exists that would produce HTML that would allow for me to roll up, say, the parent stuff to something like this:

```
Hierarchy Object
(
    + [parent:private] => Hierarchy Object
    [level:private] => 1
)
```

and then re-expand it by clicking on the +?

Comment: `print_r`/`var_dump` are good tools for "fast-debugging". But if you need more advanded tool - just use real debugger.

Comment: Yeah, but starting PHPed every time, waiting a few seconds, finding my way to the Locals window, and manually expanding everything is very frustrating and time consuming.  But print_r() gives so much data it's not so much better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, it's available as the [Krumo](http://krumo.sourceforge.net/) project.**

Comment: Yeah, when I use Krumo, it just says:

 ...  (Object) Hierarchy  

And won't let me see *any* properties or anything.

Comment: Is it possible to send a Krumo output in am email?